# What is the command-line for rar and unrar?

Tags: c#, winrar

What is the command-line for rar and unrar?

I need to rar test.txt to test.rar, and to unrar test.rar to test.txt.

I need to put this functionality in a C# WinForm.

I have Windows XP and WinRar install

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a general rule, don't shell out to other applications (ESPECIALLY ones that don't come with Windows) unless you really, really have to. See Blaenk's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.respower.com/page_tutorial_unrar

So the commands are:  `rar` and `unrar`

Source:  I googled it.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at [SevenZipSharp](http://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/) which supports RAR format as well as others. This way you won't have to rely on external applications.

Answer (score 0):

[SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/) might help (I'm not sure if they support RAR but you can compress the files in other formats i.e ZIP)

Answer (score 0):

You should clear out your question and tag it correctly.

Do you ask for the command line parameters for winrar?
For this a simple `rar /?` should help you out.

Or do you ask for a way to unrar packages via .NET-libraries?.
For that the other answers give you lot of information already.

Anyway, your commenter is right, do not shell out to programs, that do not come with the system, unless your installer ensures the other program to be there.